# How can I select multiple items in RecyclerView and add them to an ArrayList(KOTLIN)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I asked this question before but I could not get any answer. So I am asking it again but this time more detailed so you guys can understand my problem. I have a RecyclerView that gets items from my Firebase database. I want to select multiple items and add highlighted items to an arraylist of strings. FYI I am using a library called Groupie. I am not using custom adapter.

**Hobbies Class**

```
class Hobbies : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hobbies)


        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()



        tophobbies.layoutManager =
            object : LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false) {
                override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
                    // force height of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height from xml
                    lp.height = recyclerlinear.height
                    return true
                }
            }

        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
        val reference = database.getReference("Hobbies")
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                    val hobbiesItem = snap.getValue(HobbiesClass::class.java)
                    if (hobbiesItem != null) {
                        adapter.add(HobbiesAdapter(hobbiesItem))

                    }
                }

                tophobbies.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })
        
    }
}
```

**HobbiesAdapter**

```
class HobbiesAdapter(val hobbyItem: HobbiesClass) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    var list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text = hobbyItem.hobbyName
        Picasso.get().load(hobbyItem.imageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.hobbyImageView)

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (viewHolder.itemView.isSelected){
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackground)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = false
            }else {
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackgroundselected)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = true
            }

        }




    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.row
    }


}
```

***HobbiesClass***

```
@Parcelize
class HobbiesClass(val hobbyName: String, val imageUrl: String,var isSelected:Boolean) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "",false)
}
```

***My item row xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameHobby"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/hobbiesbackground">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hobbynameTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Camping"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/extralight"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hobbyImageView"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can change items background with

```
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (viewHolder.itemView.isSelected){
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackground)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = false
            }else {
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackgroundselected)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = true
            }
}
```

What I want to do is: Add the selected elements names to my arraylist. If I use the code provided under it adds the name string to the array but when I click to another one the previous one gets deleted.(It looks like the array is not saved, it resets everytime I press an item) Also if I click on multiple items rapidly then it adds them. But if I click on an item split second later all previous items from the arraylist get deleted. How can I fix this? I have looked on multiple videos but still could not get any answers.

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            list.add(viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text.toString())
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I knew the problem that was making my arraylist reset everytime was that the bind method runs everytime it is clicked. So I made a mutable list called selectedList in my Hobbies class where the recyclerview is stored. Then I past it as a parameter in my HobbiesAdapter. Then in My Hobbies class I changed the adapter from adapter.add(HobbiesAdapter(hobbiesItem))
to adapter.add(HobbiesAdapter(hobbiesItem,selectedItems))

Here is how my code looks like now. I hope it will help others in the future

**Hobbies class**

```
class Hobbies : AppCompatActivity(){
    private val selectedItems = mutableListOf<String>()

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hobbies)


        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()



        tophobbies.layoutManager =
            object : LinearLayoutManager(this, HORIZONTAL, false) {
                override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
                    // force height of viewHolder here, this will override layout_height from xml
                    lp.height = recyclerlinear.height
                    return true
                }
            }

        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
        val reference = database.getReference("Hobbies")
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                    val hobbiesItem = snap.getValue(HobbiesClass::class.java)
                    if (hobbiesItem != null) {
                        adapter.add(HobbiesAdapter(hobbiesItem,selectedItems))

                    }
                }

                tophobbies.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }

        })

        
        letsgobtn.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Selected item is ${selectedItems.toString()}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }
}
```

**HobbiesAdapter class**

```
class HobbiesAdapter(val hobbyItem: HobbiesClass,val selectedItems: MutableList<String>) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {


    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text = hobbyItem.hobbyName
        Picasso.get().load(hobbyItem.imageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.hobbyImageView)


        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (viewHolder.itemView.isSelected){
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackground)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = false
                selectedItems.remove(viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text.toString())
            }else {
                viewHolder.itemView.frameHobby.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hobbiesbackgroundselected)
                viewHolder.itemView.isSelected = true
                selectedItems.add(viewHolder.itemView.hobbynameTV.text.toString())
            }


        }

    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.row
    }

}
```

**HobbiesClass class**

```
@Parcelize
class HobbiesClass(val hobbyName: String, val imageUrl: String,var isSelected:Boolean) : Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "",false)
}
```